# Try Except for one variable in multiple variables

Tags: python

I am reading every row in a dataframe and assigning its values in each column to the variables
The dataframe created using this code

```
data = [['tom', 10], [, 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
```

So after using data.head()

```
    Name    Age
0   tom     10
1           15
2   juli    14
```

I want to assign every name to a local variable but what if one name is missing like here how can I do a try and except for this value to assign it automatically 0

```
try:
    name1 = ...
    name2 = ... #What is missing
    name3 = ...
except:
    name2 = "Not available"
```

Remember that if its another name not necessary name 2, what can I do here?

Comment: what should happen if there is a mismatch?

Comment: whats the use case here?

Comment: so basically, like `dict.get` but for a list?

Comment: I really wish there were a `list.get` method...

Comment: "I want to get each value in the list into one variable where if the 5th value is missing assign it to zero (not only fifth) any variable missing assign it to zero" I can't understand what this means. If `user_input = [2,3,4,7]`, then **exactly what** should the output be? Why? According to what logic? Where you have shown us `my_list = [2,3,4,6,7]`, *what does this have to do with the problem*? Is it a user input, or is it something already in the program? Is it supposed to help us understand what to do with the `user_input`? If so, how?

Comment: What does "get each value in the list into one variable" mean? After the code runs, how many variables are there - just one, or a separate one for each value? Should the variable(s) hold a complete list, or one number, or what?

Comment: I modified the Question to be more clear

Comment: After reading the edit, I am even more confused. Now I can't even think of questions to ask in order to try to understand the problem properly. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Please start over, and show: 1) code that someone else can **copy and paste, without modification**, in order to get the necessary input for the problem. 2) the **exact** desired output *for that specific input*.

Comment: "I want to assign every value to a local variable but what if one variable is missing" **What do you mean by** "missing"? Dataframes contain rectangular data. Cells cannot be "empty". They might store e.g. `np.nan`, but they still have a value.

Comment: I added the complete example, please check and let me know it makes sense now or not

Comment: I assume https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73169076 is a fresh attempt at the same question?

Answer (score 0):

One idiom is to append 0s to your list, then unpack a *slice*.

```
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = (user_input + [0]*5)[:5]
```

If the user input has 5 items, those are the contents of the slice. If not, the slice is padded with however many zeros from `[0]*5` are needed to make a list of 5 items.

However, there is no way to tell which of the following was intended for `[1,2,3,4]`:

1. `[0,1,2,3,4]`
2. `[1,0,2,3,4]`
3. `[1,2,0,3,4]`
4. `[1,2,3,0,4]`
5. `[1,2,3,4,0]`

so if you don't want to assume that the *trailing* elements are missing, you are better off raising an exception and forcing the user to specify 5 items. (Or switch to input that explicitly indicates which value goes with which position.)

Comment: Are you confident that you understand what OP is actually asking for? Because I have **absolutely no idea**.  If you are confident, could you please edit it appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the use case, but you could always subclass `list` so that it works how you're expecting it to.  You'd also need to remember to use `MyList()` as a wrapper around the original list.

```py
class MyCallableList(list):

    def __call__(self, idx: int, default=0):
        try:
            return self[idx]
        except IndexError:
            return default


my_list = MyCallableList([2, 3, 4, 6, 7])

assert my_list(0) == 2
assert my_list(3) == 6
assert my_list(5) == 0
```