# Assign variables to a pandas dataframe when specific cell is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I am assigning some variables to values from a data frame.
The data frame created using this code

```
data = [['tom', 10], ["", 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
```

So after using data.head()

```
    Name    Age
0   tom     10
1           15
2   juli    14
```

if one name or more names are missing or it's defined as an empty string like here. I would like to assign a variable whenever there is an empty string

Comment: The name isn't missing, it's an empty string. Assigning an empty string doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: Why are you using separate variables instead of just referring to the dataframe directly? How will you change the number of variables to match the number of rows?

Comment: Why would `0` be a sensible default value, if the "not missing" values are strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try Except for one variable in multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73168793/try-except-for-one-variable-in-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `try/except` since assigning an empty string isn't an error.

Just check the value being assigned, and replace it with `Not available` when it's empty.

```
name1 = df.iloc[0]['Name'] or 'Not available'
name2 = df.iloc[1]['Name'] or 'Not available'
name3 = df.iloc[2]['Name'] or 'Not available'
```